# Remove debug output from console output with ant/testng

Tags: java, ant, testng

I have an Ant script that runs our TestNG tests and the amount of console output is incredible and our jenkins job console logs are over a gigabyte.  There are lots of DEBUG outputs in the logs and I have the log4j settings to only log INFO so I'm not sure where all this other input is coming from.  Any ideas on how to reduce the amount of output to the console?  Here is an example of some of the output I don't care about:

```
[testng] 15:45:03.746 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl - Interceptors contributed by databinding: []
[testng] 15:45:03.750 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@6279f936 to phase setup
[testng] 15:45:03.750 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@35d87abc to phase prepare-send
[testng] 15:45:03.750 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@1761e842 to phase pre-logical
[testng] 15:45:03.750 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@1cd7510c to phase pre-logical
[testng] 15:45:03.750 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@7c09f99e to phase pre-logical
```

Comment: Do you know what logger is being used (eg: log4j, slf4j, etc.)?

Comment: log4j, but it seems like maybe there is a conflict: [testng] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
   [testng] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/lib/logback-classic-0.9.29.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   [testng] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   [testng] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
   [testng] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.DefaultContextSelector]

Comment: Sounds like you're having slf4j config issues.  I could explain the way sl4j works and how to configure it, but maybe you already know all that information?  I'd get rid of that warning first.

Comment: Ok so I fixed the SLF4J warnings and I'm still getting all that DEBUG output.  I put verbose="1" in my testng ant taskdef call, and still the same thing.

Comment: I think it's more likely that the classpath has this configured.  There's probably a logging file somewhere that is setting the minimum level to DEBUG.

Comment: The only logging properties file is the log4j.properties which has log4j.rootLogger=info

Comment: I believe any jar in your classpath can have a log4j.properties file.  If it gets loaded first, that will be the one used.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ant script is invoked with any of the `-d` or `-v` options. If yes, you want to remove them.

`-v` enables verbose output while `-d` enables debug (even more verbose) output.

Comment: The ant script does not have -d/-v.  I tried running it with -q and it had no output.